# Firebase scaled queries on ranking

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app via Firebase, and I have a question about the scalability of my database node. I decentralized my data, but when I try to rank posts (based on # likes), I can't seem to find a good solution. I've got a page with the top 10 most liked songs of the last 30 days, but I've got some concerns about this query if the app scales. At this point, a few hundred to a few thousand songs are posted, but what if that node consists of a few million?

The structure is like this:

```
"totalSongs" : {
   "-KHjnJcG2av6nyIEP1Wu" : {
      "author" : "64df19dd-68fb-43cb-ab1b-b8e9f55cf",
      "date" : 1463238347457,
      "key" : "KHjnJcG2av6nyIEP1Wu",
      "likesCount" : 3,
      "name" : "anna",
      "reasonUpload" : "-its good mayne",
      "uploadTitle" : "A tribe called quest - we got the jazz",
      "uploadUrl" : "cxN4nKk2cfk"
    },
    "-KHkUAJ48h-3k6HIDOri" : {
      "author" : "64df19dd-68fb-43cb-ab1b-b8e9f51cf",
      "date" : 1463249843668,
      "key" : "-KHkUAJ48h-3k6HIDOri",
      "likesCount" : 6,
      "name" : "peter",
      "reasonUpload" : "-summer vibes",
      "uploadTitle" : "Kool & The Gang",
      "uploadUrl" : "2SFt7JHwJeg"
    }
}
```

The above JSON shows two uploads. I can rank them via 'LikesCount' and this works (via angularJS, ng-repeat, orderBy: '-likesCount'), but what if there are 4 million uploads? I was thinking about maken a new node (e.g. totalSongs2, totalSongs3) every 30 days, to have a node that consists of the uploads in that timeframe, but this seems somewhat strange. How hard is it for Firebase to query such a node and how can I do this a different way?

Answer (score 0):

4 million uploads? I am guessing you are on purchased Firebase package to do that huge amount.

It depends how you want to organise your JSON structure. I would have suggested to implement this in corresponding to dates and as you expand the child nodes, you have unique identifiers that list the total songs uploaded in that period.

Any further complicated to more child nodes make your code messy.  It is not difficult for Firebase to query anything, the issue could be how heavy task performance will your concurrent connection be?  There is a limit for the free package but unlimited on the purchased package.

JSON doesn't require much disk usage, but Firebase structure could be utilised better for scabability if you do 10 databases in their free package.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 4 million uploads is just a hypothesis, but the reason for my question is that if this will lead to problems in the future, I'd rather tackle them now. And yes, within a few months I will use the purchased package.

Comment: @Zizazorro 4 million for purchased package shouldn't be a problem. purchase package has BigQuery SQL queries so you go to many Gigabytes.  I work with Big Data and BigQuery on Firebase purchased package can do millions perfectly fine.  Scalability won't be an issue, Firebase got that covered for their consumers.

Comment: Nice, I will look into that! Thanks